# Error while trying to set config in tigrc

Tags: tig

I've below line in my tigrc file

```
set commit-title-graph = no
```

I'm getting this error when I run any tig command, and I'm not able to fine what it the issue.

```
tig warning: ~/.tigrc:1: Unknown option name: commit-title-graph
tig warning: Errors while loading /Users/johndoe/.tigrc.
```

Comment: Are you using the latest version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `man tigrc`, `commit-title` is one of options in `View Settings`, not a variable. So the use case is like this:

```
set main-view = \
    date:relative \
    author:abbreviated \
    id \
    commit-title:graph=v2,refs=true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set it like this:

```
set main-view-commit-title-graph = no
```

This way you only modify the option you want and don't have to rebuild the whole view from scratch.

It took me a little while to figure it out, but there's a hierarchical structure to the options.

Comment: Here are a few more examples from my `.tigrc`:
`set main-view-id-display = true`,
`set main-view-author-width = 18`,
`set main-options = --all`.